# How can I do for loop for my nodejs or anyway to shortcut my duplicate code

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to create a array of rules and maximum rule we can have is 4.

Here is my backend to create rules:

```
  const rules = [];

  const rules = [
    req.body.rule_0,
    req.body.rule_1,
    req.body.rule_2,
    req.body.rule_3,
  ];

  console.log(rules);
      const payload = {
        title: req.body.title,
        mission: req.body.mission,
        picture: picture,
        inputs: req.body.inputs,
        outputs: req.body.outputs,
        duration_in_months: req.body.duration_in_months,
        status: req.body.status,
        rules: rules,
        mergedTo: teamId,
      };
```

is there anyways I can shortcut the way I push in my array?

Comment: Change the request to have not such an odd structure IMO. Have it send a single rule instead, or an array of rules if needed, and then select the first one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a loop:

```js
const rules = [];
for(let ii=0; ii<4; ii++) {
  const rule = req.body[`rule_${ii}`];
  if (rule) rules.push(rule);
}
```

Comment: Is it automatic set the array have the length of 4?

Comment: @nathan I don't fully understand your question. Can you rephrase?

Comment: I mean like if I just send `rule_0` and `rule_1` to backend but the backend still consider we have `rule_2` and 3 was sent and it set it to undefined.

Comment: How can we avoid the undefined value

Comment: @nathan if your array is not supposed to contain things like 0, null, undefined, false then try something like `const wantedRules = rules.filter(el => el)` that's gonna remove all falsy values from the array or in the code in answer `if((req.body[\`rule_${ii}\`) { rules.push(req.body[\`rule_${ii}\`]); }` if you don't wanna add it from the start

Comment: @nathan what do you want to happen if not enough rules are submitted?

Comment: @Evert create the with `rule_${ii}` if it was sent to backend. Like if I sent `rule_0` and `rule_1` it will create array of `[rule_0 , rule_1]` not like `[rule_0,rule_1, undefined, undefined]`

Comment: @Evert thanks for helping me out but when I sent 2 rules to my backend it did just created array of 2 but when I click edit in front end and add more rule like 3-4 it will replace data my rule 1-2 with data 3-4

Comment: @nathan that sounds like a completely separate problem. We can't keep talking until you have a working application.